# Picasso's .fit() is off by some pixels

Tags: android, imageview, scale, picasso

I have an `ImageView` with fixed `layout_height` and `layout_width` and a frame which is in it's background (code below).

I want to load an image into it using picasso and make the image fit the `ImageView` bounds.

My `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
            android:id="@+id/upload_photo_row_image"
            android:layout_width="99dp"
            android:layout_height="72dp"
            android:background="@drawable/background_photo_frame"
            android:padding="4dp"/>
```

`background_photo_frame` :

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <solid android:color="@android:color/transparent"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="4 dp"
        android:color="@color/pure_white"/>
</shape>
```

Picasso loading code:

```
Picasso.with(getContext()).load(uri).fit().centerCrop().into(imageView)
```

Picasso version:

```
compile 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.0'
```

With this code the image is a bit smaller in width than it should be and as visible in the image below (The `background_color` of the containing `ViewGroup` has been set to red to illustrate the bug):

[image]

I can fix this bu adding the attribute `android:scaleType="fitXY"` to my `ImageView`. Is there something I am doing wrong or is this a bug in `Picasso`?

Answer (score 0):

What version are you using? This should be fixed in the latest version (2.5.0 as of 2015 Feb 28)